# Error parsing AndroidManifest.xml in Flutter project: 'Error parsing LocalFile

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter project where I'm getting the following error message during the build process:

```
Error parsing LocalFile: 'D:\adibi_project\flutter_application_hafte15\flutter_application_1\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'
Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and try again.
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file is :

[image]

I wanted to add deep link to this file, and this problem occurred. What is your solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the slash to close the first intent-filter.

```
</intent-filter>
```